# Can anyone help identify this World War One uniform?

Tags: world-war-one, identification, uniform

[image]I have this photograph of my grandfather in uniform - taken in Seaford, Sussex, England, some time after 1914.  Can anyone tell me anything about this uniform?  He eventually joined 525 coy. 62nd Division of the Army Service Corps. Thanks

[image: grandfather in uniform]

Comment: Was he a horseman?

Comment: Yes, I have another picture of him mounted on horseback.  He was a 2nd. Lt. in charge of the wagon trains that supplied the front line on the Somme in 1917-18.

Comment: I think I can make out his rank badge on his epaulettes: one pip, consistent with being 2nd lieutenant.  His pose, with riding crop and britches, projects   self-confidence in his specialty, and importance.  The aiguillette on his shoulder presumably indicates something good about his job but I don't know enough to say what, precisely.

Comment: It might help if you uploaded the other picture (unless he's wearing a different uniform in it). There may be other visual clues aside from the uniform itself which could prove helpful.

Comment: @kimchilover He does not appear to be wearing an officer's uniform who tended to have lapels on their jackets. I suspect the pips you're seeing are the Royal Service Corps badge or similar. Officers in this period wore their rank on their lower sleeves. The riding crop and breeches are typical for all members of units that used horses. The pose is typical for the time and has nothing to do with rank. The lanyard appears to be common too amongst all ranks though I don't know what it signifies. It might represent a minimum time in the service for instance.

Comment: Thanks - another picture uploaded just now.

Comment: Single Bath Star on wrist confirms @kimchilover's evaluation of rank-2nd Lt.

Comment: A quibble about the original question's last sentence.  Company 525 of the ASC was attached to the "62nd (West Riding) Division", which was not part of the ASC but a regular fighting unit.

Comment: Re: quibble - yes I'm a bit puzzled by that too, but one one postcard home he gives his address as Headquarters Coy. 62nd Divisional Train ASC, BEF.  At another time he was in 525 Coy.

Comment: @DavidSC That train address just means his unit was part of the supply train that supplied the 62nd. It's no different that ordering an uber to pick you up from your friend's house. You give their address because that's where you are, not because you are part of their household.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1):

Your Grandfather in the first photo is wearing the khaki service dress for officers of the army which included a lapel-led tunic introduced in 1908 with a shirt and tie which became khaki like the tunic from amendments of the 1st of August 1913 he also wears the standard Sam Browne belt issued to all officers from 1900 onwards.
The second photo of him shows him to wear the 1902 pattern service dress introduced to lower ranks (not officers).

Uniform for Officers updated by the 1913 Amendments. [image]
1902 Pattern service dress
[image]

[source](https://www.militaria.at/Book.aspx?book=538650&Language=en)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  It is most helpful in dating the two photographs - the lower one is probably taken at the time he joined up, and the one above after he was promoted to 2nd Lieutenant. 
Many thanks, 
David

Comment: No problem i saw that you were struggling so I decided to help even though you knew about his service i thought you might find it interesting to add information about the uniforms themselves.